# In React how to import only needed Bootstrap styles. Bootstrap css modules?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I want to use bootstrap 4 in my React project. 
The built css file should have only styles of bootstrap classes that I included in my React components.

I am not searching for Bootstrap css classes as React components; I don't mind to write `<div className='container'>`

#### 1. Reactstrap

I tried with [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap), and yes has bootstrap css classes as components (e.g `<Container></Container>`) but you have to includes **all bootstrap styles**:

In `src/index.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

#### 2. Scss source files

Because I already had `sass-loader` I tried importing directly the scss file:

```
import bootstrapGrid from 'bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss';
const myComponent = () => <div className={bootstrapGrid.container}>[...]</div>
```

But it fails as it doesn't have enough data to compile:

[image]

#### 3. Oher solutions:

- [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) I don't need js logic in react way (and it is v3)
- [styled-bootstrap](https://github.com/xDae/styled-bootstrap) still too new
- [bootstrap-css-modules](https://github.com/adamelliotfields/bootstrap-css-modules) seems good, but it is unmaintained

What is the right direction?

Or should I go for [purifycss-webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack) to clean up my App? And remove unused css classes.

Comment: You need to import Bootstrap's variables.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following which should include all the necessary modules to compile just the grid:

```
import bootstrapGrid from 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';
```

Or, include variables first & all other modules that are needed to compile the grid:

```
import bootstrapFunctions from 'bootstrap/scss/_functions';
import bootstrapVariables from 'bootstrap/scss/_variables';
import bootstrapMixinBreakpoints from 'bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';
import bootstrapMixinGridFramework from 'bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid-framework';
import bootstrapMixinGrid from 'bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid';
import bootstrapGrid from 'bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss';
import bootstrapUtilitiesDisplay from 'bootstrap/scss/utilities/_display';
import bootstrapUtilitiesFlex from 'bootstrap/scss/utilities/_flex';
```

You can check which modules are needed from the bootstrap-grid.scss file `@imports`:

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";

@import "mixins/breakpoints";
@import "mixins/grid-framework";
@import "mixins/grid";

@import "grid";
@import "utilities/display";
@import "utilities/flex";
```

Comment: With `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss` it works but then I am importing the whole grid. `.container ` was just an example. Importing one by one it fails to compile `Argument $color of darken($color, $amount) must be a color`. It seems when importing variables, functions and mixins are not global.

Comment: Sorry for late reply Mikel, what do you mean by "whole grid"? it just includes all imports. The error you are getting is the lack of  the `$color` variable definition which is used as argument.